# How to upload source maps in react native sentry without expo

Tags: react-native, source-maps, sentry, react-native-sentry

How to upload source maps to sentry correctly for react native without using expo.I have tried manual uploading source maps and automated by using sentry webpack plugin.But nothing seems to work.Even if am trying with webpack i have followed the docs after creating a webpack.config.js and adding neccessary code code what else all needs to be done as its not uploading maps.Also in manual upload source maps are not detected by issue.